# Glyphicons not showing up in Angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I'm taking an online Angular course and the "glyphicon" classes used by the instructor don't work for me. Granted this is a 3 year old course so things might have changed since then but I was just wondering if anyone could see anything wrong with my code or if there additional steps needed to get glyphicons to show up.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="zippy">
<div class="zippy-heading"
[class.expanded]="isExpanded"
(click)="toggle()"
>
    {{ title }}
    <span class="glyphicon"
        [ngClass] ="{
            'glyphicon-chevron-up':isExpanded,
            'glyphicon-chevron-down': !isExpanded
        }"
    ></span>
</div>
<div *ngIf="isExpanded" class="zippy-body"></div>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just read Bootstrap 4 doesn't support Glyphicons. Problem solved.